# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /home/smoto/public_html/contact-us/index.php on line 150

Tags: php

Just noticed the error, I can't see where the problem is. Line 150 it's referring to is the first `echo` line `Fail to Send...` Can you please help me out?

```
//ADMIN_EMAIL               
    $sendEmail = mail('info@domain.ca, sherri@domain.ca’,$subject,$emailContent,$headers);
    if($sendEmail == 0){
        echo '<p class="cautions">Fail to Send Notification Email to Admin.</p>';
    }else{
        echo '<p class="confirm">Thank you for your interest in iTTTi Vancouver.<br />Your request has been received and you will be contacted within 3 business days.</p>';
    }
```

Comment: You have invalid quotes around your mail parameters `’`. Try changing them to this `'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the mail function. you have a special character where you intent to have a quote. Look closely at `sherri@domain.ca’,` The syntax highlighting gives you a clue. Notice that it changes color when you start your quote, but does not return to normal color where you'd expect it to.

Comment: If you don't have an editor that includes Syntax Highlighting, I'd recomment [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

Comment: may i suggest that if you do not have an editor that does syntax highlighting then you are working way too hard. ;-/ And, yes, i am 'old school'.